# Can't connect to IBMMQ MQRC_NOT_UNAUTHORIZED

Tags: java, ibm-mq

I have installed IBMMQ 9.0 in windows running in virtualbox in my local and I have sample java code sending message to MQ.

here is the java code

```
 MQQueueConnectionFactory cf = new MQQueueConnectionFactory();
 cf.setHostName(MY_IP);
 cf.setPort(1417);
 cf.setTransportType(WMQConstants.WMQ_CM_CLIENT);
 cf.setQueueManager("QM1_TEST");
 cf.setChannel("QM1_TEST.CH");
 MQQueueConnection connection = (MQQueueConnection)
 cf.createQueueConnection();
 MQQueueSession session = (MQQueueSession)
 connection.createQueueSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
 MQQueue queue = (MQQueue) session.createQueue("queue:///QUEUE_TEST");
 MQQueueSender sender = (MQQueueSender) session.createSender(queue);
 String message = "Test Message";
 TextMessage textMessage = (TextMessage)   
 session.createTextMessage(message);
 connection.start();
 sender.send(textMessage);
```

The program receives this error.

```
com.ibm.msg.client.jms.DetailedJMSSecurityException: JMSWMQ2013: The
security authentication was not valid that was supplied for QueueManager  
'QM1_TEST' with connection mode 'Client' and host name '192.168.0.24(1417)'.
Please check if the supplied username and password are correct on the  
QueueManager to which you are connecting. at
com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.internal.Reason.reasonToException(Reason.java:531)
at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.internal.Reason.createException(Reason.java:215)
at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQConnection.<init>(WMQConnection.java:424)
at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.factories.WMQConnectionFactory.createV7ProviderConnection(WMQConnectionFactory.java:8475)
at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.factories.WMQConnectionFactory.createProviderConnection(WMQConnectionFactory.java:7815)
at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.admin.JmsConnectionFactoryImpl._createConnection(JmsConnectionFactoryImpl.java:303)
at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.admin.JmsConnectionFactoryImpl.createConnection(JmsConnectionFactoryImpl.java:236)
at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQConnectionFactory.createCommonConnection(MQConnectionFactory.java:6016)
at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactory.createQueueConnection(MQQueueConnectionFactory.java:111)
at com.cwt.bpg.cbr.demo.ibm.mq.client.SendMessage.main(SendMessage.java:24)
Caused by: com.ibm.mq.MQException: JMSCMQ0001: IBM MQ call failed with compcode '2' ('MQCC_FAILED') reason '2035' ('MQRC_NOT_AUTHORIZED').
at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.internal.Reason.createException(Reason.java:203)
... 8 more
```

Here is the log under my queue manager with significant details.

```
5/21/2018 16:42:46 - Process(4984.8) User(MUSR_MQADMIN) Program
(amqrmppa.exe) Host(MSEDGEWIN10) Installation(Installation1) VRMF(9.0.0.0) 
QMgr(QM1_DEV) AMQ9776: Channel was blocked by userid 
EXPLANATION: 
The inbound channel 'QM1_DEV.CH' was blocked from address '10.xx.xx.xx' 
because the active values of the channel were mapped to a userid which    
should be blocked. The active values of the channel were 'MCAUSER(IEUser) 
CLNTUSER(IEUser) ADDRESS(LWPHL1U012FXP)'
```

Comment: Does the user you run the java process as have permission to connect to the queue manager and open the queue? Look for a file under the queue manager directory called AMQERR01.LOG, it will have entries explaining why the connection failed.

Comment: I did  not provide any user credentials in my java code and I did not provide any username and passsword during my installation of IBMMQ. Is it using the OS user credentials?

Comment: Check the log like I said.

Comment: You can edit your question to include the additional information from the log.

Comment: Run this command to see which rule is blocking it: `DIS CHLAUTH(QM1_DEV.CH) TYPE(ALL) CLNTUSER('IEUser') ADDRESS(10.xx.xx.xx) MATCH(RUNCHECK)` .  Likely it is because MQ considers `IEUser` to be an administrative user either because it is a member of the local mqm group or is a Windows administrator.

Answer (score 0):

You are not providing a user and password, your are connecting with the default user identity.

```
QueueConnection createQueueConnection()
Creates a queue connection with default user identity.
```

You can either provide credentials:

```
QueueConnection createQueueConnection(String userid,String password)
```

By default the userid and password for any user in the `mqm` group on the MQ broker will have access to the queue managers.

The IBM MQ docs also have instructions for disabling security altogether.

Comment: Applications should not connect to MQ using users in the mqm group. this should be reserved for administrators of the MQ product.

Comment: Note that mq 7.1 and higher will block mq admin users such as members of the mqm group by default.